# What is wrong, I've used the relevant GetX widget and it still throws this error

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

This is the code where the error occurred using GetX. If anyone want to help thanks for advance

```dart
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: [
              Expanded(
                child: GetX<CustomerController> (
                  builder: (customerController) {
                    return ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: customerController.count,
                      itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      return ListTile(
                      selectedTileColor:Colors.blueGrey.shade50,
                      title: Text(customerController.results.string),      
                      );
                    });
                  },
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
```

Comment: You don't have a RxType variable Inside GetX that's why it shown an error. "controller. count" or "customerController.results.string" should be obs. Changing variable type into RxType

Answer (score 1):

Create a GetX Controller and then assign it to your GetX Widget

```
GetX<ControllerName>(
            builder: (customerController) {
              return ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: customerController.controllervalueinobx.length, //should be obx/Rx type variable
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return ListTile(
                      selectedTileColor: Colors.blueGrey.shade50,
                      title: Text(
                        "customerController.results.string",
       ),                        );
                  });
            },
          ),
```